# Login: Unable to authenticate user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

I am trying to login but the below code always returning below error though the email and password is correct

> Authentication failed! Incorrect Password!

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {

  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).json({ authenticated: false, message: 'Email is not registered yet! Please Signup and try Signin' });
    } else {
      // Check if password matches
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch) => {
         if (!isMatch) return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Authentication failed! Incorrect Password!' });
        // Make sure the user has been verified
         if (!user.isVerified) return res.status(401).send({ type: 'not-verified', message: 'Your account has not been verified. Please check your email' }); 

        if (isMatch) {
           const userInfo = setUserInfo(user);
            console.log("userInfo: ", userInfo)
          res.status(200).json({
            token: `${generateToken(userInfo)}`,
            user: userInfo
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but it doesn't seem like you are comparing the password against anything? Maybe your `comparePassword` function is written incorrectly.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for pointing to the right path.  I had this issue because of changing this UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) { to an arrow function UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = (candidatePassword, cb) => {. Don't understand why arrow function didn't work in this case